# Unity C# How to avoid the tap and move by character only by swiping

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move my player by swiping / dragging, the swipe works fine, however if I tap in any part of the screen it teleports my character to that position. I have already tried using other methods to move it (like transform.translate or rb.velocity) but it doesn't feel fluid enough. So i'm a little bit lost in order to solve it, here is my code:

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
 {
     Vector2 curScreenPoint = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
     Vector2 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint);
     rb.MovePosition(curPosition);
 }
```

Comment: You want to move character only by dragging/swiping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're setting player's position by tap's position.
you can edit it to player's position changes according to swipe distance:

```
Vector2 startPosition ;
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
     Vector2 curScreenPoint = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
     startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint);
}

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Vector2 curScreenPoint = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint);
    transform.position += (curPosition - startPosition);
    startPosition = curPosition;
}
```

I don't know if the code is working correctly, but the idea is so.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you can use for dragging/swiping the player without getting it teleported;
Add this script to your player.
This would work for any circle object else if your object contain any other collider replace circle collider with the required collider

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour {


    // touch offset allows ball not to shake when it starts moving
    float deltaX, deltaY;


    // reference to Rigidbody2D component
    Rigidbody2D rb;


    // ball movement not allowed if you touches not the ball at the first time
    bool moveAllowed = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();


        // Add bouncy material tha ball
        PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D ();
        mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
        mat.friction = 0.4f;
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().sharedMaterial = mat;


    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        // Initiating touch event
        // if touch event takes place
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {


        // get touch position
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);


        // obtain touch position
        Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touch.position);


            // get touch to take a deal with
            switch (touch.phase) {


            // if you touches the screen
            case TouchPhase.Began:


                // if you touch the ball
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D> () == Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos)) {


                    // get the offset between position you touches
                    // and the center of the game object
                    deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                    deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;


                    // if touch begins within the ball collider
                    // then it is allowed to move
                    moveAllowed = true;


                    // restrict some rigidbody properties so it moves
                    // more  smoothly and correctly
                    rb.freezeRotation = true;
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (0, 0);
                    rb.gravityScale = 0;
                    GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().sharedMaterial = null;
                }
                break;


                // you move your finger
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                // if you touches the ball and movement is allowed then move
                if (GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> () == Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos) && moveAllowed)
                    rb.MovePosition (new Vector2 (touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY));
                break;


                // you release your finger
            case TouchPhase.Ended:


                // restore initial parameters
                // when touch is ended
                moveAllowed = false;
                rb.freezeRotation = false;
                rb.gravityScale = 2;
                PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D ();
                mat.bounciness = 0.75f;
                mat.friction = 0.4f;
                GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ().sharedMaterial = mat;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It is for android

Answer (score -1):

You can use  free touch or swipe  package for it.
First,You need to chooese a free tool from asset store then, this tool probably will include swipe and tap events seperately.I think this will help you.

Comment: try to post some code not just a pre made asset store links. atleast post he link of the asset you are talking about.